# Using wget and grep to download HTML pages and filter by keywords

Tags: linux, grep, wget

```
KEYWORDS=("dolphins" "fish" "dogs" "cats" "iguanas")
IFS=$'\n'
find . -type f -size +1c ! -exec grep -qF "${KEYWORDS[*]}" {} \; -exec truncate -s 0 -f {} \;
```

---

If a file is over 1 byte, search for keywords. If keyword is not found, truncate it to 0 bytes. I get the following error:

```
truncate: invalid option -- 'f'
Try `truncate --help' for more information.
```

Comment: You're supposed to change `http://www.url.com` to the actual URL you are using.

Comment: Do you want to delete the file unless it contains _at least one_ of your keywords or delete if it does not contain _all_ of them?

Comment: Terdon: I want to delete the file unless it contains at least one of my keywords. Another concern I have is if GREP is deleting the file (the wget -U [unique] command will be rendered useless) and the same link could be downloaded\deleted 100 times over again.

Comment: See my answer for one way to do this. As for your second concern, well yes. Obviously, if you delete the files, they will be downloaded again if your run the same script. I don't understand how else this could work. By the way, `wget -U` does *not* mean unique, it defines the user agent (mozilla in your case).

Answer (score 2):

When using extended or Perl regular expressions, `grep` can take multiple search patterns separated by a pipe (`|`):

```
   -E, --extended-regexp
          Interpret  PATTERN  as  an extended regular expression (ERE, see
          below).  (-E is specified by POSIX.)

   -P, --perl-regexp
          Interpret  PATTERN  as  a  Perl  regular  expression  (PCRE, see
          below).  This is highly experimental and grep  -P  may  warn  of
          unimplemented features.
```

This means that you don't need to declare an array for your kewords, you can just combine them into a single string, separated by `|`. This makes your script much easier:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

wget --no-clobber -r -E -e robots=off -U mozilla -R gif,jpeg,tif,jpg,pdf,bmp,png,css,js http://www.url.com

KEYWORDS='dolphins|fish|dogs|cats|iguanas'

for file in **; do
    if [[ -r "$file" ]] && [[ -f file ]] ! grep -wqP "$KEYWORDS" "$file"; then
          rm -f "$file" 
    fi
done
```

Comment: This appears to be writing to the remote location instead of the directory where I'm executing the script locally. See: Cannot write to `www.url.com/message/dmca_policy.html' (Permission denied).
grep: www.url.com: Is a directory
rm: cannot remove `www.url.com': Is a directory

Comment: @Guestinneedofhelp OK, so you have multiple files and folders in your target directory (you should have said that in your question). Do you want to seach through all files in all subdirectories?

Comment: I don't actually have them yet. The wget function will download them, then the grep command will delete them if the keyword is not contained in the file.

Comment: @Guestinneedofhelp umm, OK, _will_ you have multiple directories then? Also, you have run the script once already and have attempted to download from the dummy address `http://www.url.com`, this means you now hoave a directory called `www.url.com`, that's what is giving you the errors.

Comment: You're right I changed the URL and there's no longer errors. It was an issue with the folder. The problem now is the files are being downloaded like usual, but none are being deleted and they certainly don't contain the keywords.

Comment: @Guestinneedofhelp the new version should deal with the `is a directory` error. The other errors you describe are because you have run this using `www.url.com` and have not deleted the directory that that created. Just use the right URL and remove the `www.url.com` directory.

Comment: It should grab a file, check for keywords, delete or continue.

Comment: @Guestinneedofhelp ARGH! Next time, please try adding some more detail and background to your question. OK, that's a completely different thing. This is definitely an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You can't check if a string is in a file without somehow downloading the file. Just download them all and delete as necessary. Your `wget` command downloads _all_ files, not one by one.

Comment: @Guestinneedofhelp look, just create a new, empty directory. Move into that directory and run the script in my answer (replacing www.url.com with the real address). It should do exactly what you want.

Comment: Why can't you check each file immediately after being downloaded with wget?

Comment: @Guestinneedofhelp because the wget command is one, long process. You can't stop it after each file is downloaded without stopping the process itself.

Answer (score 2):

```
KEYWORDS=("dolphins" "fish" "dogs" "cats" "iguanas")
IFS=$'\n'
find . -type f ! -exec grep -qF "${KEYWORDS[*]}" {} \; -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Would delete the files that have none of the keywords.

Comment: well, the problem is... the wget...

Comment: KEYWORDS=("dolphins" "fish" "dogs" "cats" "iguanas")
IFS=$'\n'
find . -type f -size +1c ! -exec grep -qF "${KEYWORDS[*]}" {} \; -exec truncate -s 0 -f {} \;


----------------------------------

I would like to use your solution, but add the following: If file is over 1 byte search for keywords else skip the file... if keyword is not found truncate to 0bytes. I get the following error:

truncate: invalid option -- 'f'
Try `truncate --help' for more information.

Comment: Remove the `-f`.

Answer (score 0):

To find any files that do not contain a specific pattern, you can use:

```
if ! grep -q $pattern "$file"; then
    # The file does not have a match
    do_stuff_to "$file"
else
    # There is a match
    do_something_else_to "$file"
fi
```

So, to use your example keywords, after your `wget`, you might use:

```
declare -a KEYWORDS
KEYWORDS=("dolphins" "fish" "dogs" "cats" "iguanas")

for keyword in ${KEYWORDS[@]}; do
    for file in **; do
    if [[ -r "$file" ]] && ! grep -q $keyword "$file"; do
        rm -f "$file"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Take a close look at how I define `KEYWORDS`.  Remove your commas.

Comment: I've made a minor edit to my example, please try again and if it still does not work, append your new script and its output as an edit to your question rather than carry out a conversation in comments.

Comment: @Guestinneedofhelp -  the website did not strip the formatting, it just did not download the required bits for formatting - use the `--page-requisites` option for that, more on that [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/downloading-entire-web-site-wget)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking forward to deleting a file that doesn't contain even a single keyword? (In other words, retain the files that contain at least one keyword?) The following presents a compact solution using GNU `grep`:

```
rm $(find . -type f -exec grep -LwE 'keyword1|keyword2|keyword3' {} +)
```

In the above, `find . -type f -exec grep -LwE 'keyword1|keyword2|keyword3' {} +` lists the name of all the file not containing any keyword. Here, three arguments are used with `grep`:

1. `w` indicates that an entire word should be matched (e.g., `grep -w get file_name` indicates that the entire word "get" should be matched in the file, and not say, forget).
2. `E` tells `grep` to match for multiple patterns. In this case, your keywords are the patterns.
3. `L` prints the file names not matching any pattern. To quote from the `man` pages:

> -L, --files-without-match
>                 Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which no  output  would  normally  have  been
>                 printed.  The scanning will stop on the first match.

So, once `find` returns a list of file names, you can delete them using `rm`.

As you are aware, `rm` would delete the files. So, please be careful while executing the above command. At first you might just execute the `find` command and manually verify it works as per your requirement.

Comment: Nice, but this will break on filenames with spaces.